# How can I get the last number from string in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Sorry, I'll explain it better

How can I get the last number from string?

Examples of generics strings:

```
If str=str1s2
echo $str | cmd? 
I get 2

If str=234ef85
echo $str | cmd? 
I get 85

 If str=djfs1d2.3
echo $str | cmd? 
I get 3
```

"cmd?" is the command/script that I want

Comment: Maybe you could count the length of the string, then iterate in reverse matching numeric, when the next match is non-numeric, you have the whole number. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-string-manipulation/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All you need is  `grep -Eo '[0-9]+$'` :

```
gv@debian:~$ echo 234ef85 |grep -Eo '[0-9]+$'          ## --> 85
gv@debian:~$ echo 234ef856 |grep -Eo '[0-9]+$'         ## --> 856
gv@debian:~$ echo 234ef85d6 |grep -Eo '[0-9]+$'        ## --> 6
gv@debian:~$ echo 234ef85d.6 |grep -Eo '[0-9]+$'       ## --> 6
gv@debian:~$ echo 234ef85d.6. |grep -Eo '[0-9]+$'      ## --> no result
gv@debian:~$ echo 234ef85d.6.1 |grep -Eo '[0-9]+$'     ## --> 1
gv@debian:~$ echo 234ef85d.6.1222 |grep -Eo '[0-9]+$'  ## --> 1222
```

Comment: Please, can you explains grep -Eo and '[0-9]+$'?

Comment: -E: extended grep, -o: only get the matching part. In regex part, it finds one or more digits ([0-9]+) just before the end of the line marked by $

Answer (score 9):

You can use parameter expansion with extglob. First, remove the number from the end, then remove what you got from the beginning.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
for str in str1s2 djfs1d2.3 fefwfw4rfe45 234ef8 ; do
    without_number=${str%%+([0-9])}
    echo ${str#$without_number}
done
```

Comment: Well done. I leaned something new. **Composite patterns**. With *extglob* enabled, there are 5 additional *composite patterns* available. (see: on or about line `1403` of `man bash`... and I've been doing this for a long-long time `:)`

Comment: This highlights an area largely unexplored.  Thanks for this

Answer (score 4):

You can use `grep` with

```
rev <<< "$str" | grep -Eo "[0-9]*" | head -1 |rev
```

EDIT:
`rev` is not needed when I use `tail -1` but the head/tail are overdone when you just add the end-of-line marker `$` like @Vasiliou did (I upvoted his answer). Without `rev` and `head` the `grep` solution is better than `sed`. 
I deleted my remark "Better is using `sed`".

```
sed -r 's/.*[^0-9]+([0-9]*)$/\1/' <<< "$str"
```

Comment: Can you explains grep -Eo ?

Comment: Really happy to see posix extended regex being used if possible - many people seem to jump straight into PCRE only ++

Comment: @alessiovolpe
The option `E` is for extended expressions, the `o` is for showing all matched substring on different lines. I edited my answer, @GeorgeVasiliou gave a better answer (you can switch selected answer to his answer).

Comment: @WalterA Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Walter. You are a nice person.

Answer (score 3):

With awk:

INPUT:

```
 str1 = "str1s2"
 str2 = "djfs1d2.3"
 str3 = "fefwfw4rfe45"
 str4 = "234ef8"
```

command:

```
tr = \  < INPUT  |
awk '{ match($2,"[0-9]*\"$"); 
       printf "%s: %s\n", $1, substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH-1);  }'
```

output:

```
str1: 2
str2: 3
str3: 45
str4: 8
```

Comment: Good on you for putting in an awk variant.

Answer (score 3):

**Get all numbers from a string:**

```sh
grep -Eo '[0-9]+'
```

**Get last number from a string:**

```sh
grep -Eo '[0-9]+' | tail -1
```

(Expanding on George's answer a bit..)

- `-E` means extended regex
- `-o` means print each matching part on a separate line

Answer (score 2):

Short ***gawk*** approach (for multiple variables):

```
echo "$str1 $str2 $str3 $str4 " | awk -v FPAT="[0-9]+ " '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "str"i": "$i}'
```

The output:

```
str1: 2 
str2: 3 
str3: 45 
str4: 8
```

---

- `FPAT="[0-9]+ "` -  a regexp that matches the fields, instead of matching the field separator

---

As you have changed your initial condition:
For one single string it would be even simpler:

```
echo djfs1d2.3 | awk -v FPAT="[0-9]+" '{print $NF}'
3
```

Comment: Nice trick. It seems that OP question can be answered directly by this FPAT approach using `awk -v FPAT="[0-9]+ " '{print $NF}'`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou, well, yes. I didn't see the OP has changed his initial input

Answer (score 2):

Just found an efficient way to do this in pure Bash with no pipes or explicit conditionals:

```
# ##            Erase all occurrences of pattern from beginning of string:
# *             Absolutely anything
# [![:digit:]]  Single non-digit character

num="${str##*[![:digit:]]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to spawn a child process, since you have regexp matching in bash. Assume for example the string

```
str=a34b56c
```

Now you can do

```
if [[ $str =~ ([0-9]+)[^0-9]*$ ]]
then
  echo The last number is ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
  echo The string "$str" does not contain digits
fi
```

The trick here is putting parenthesis around that part of the pattern which makes up the number. This allows you to pick up the number using `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`.